what is the onpoint, offpoint, inpoint and outpoint?
consider :
Units>200
(units greater than 200)
Now what is the onpoint, offpoint, inpoint and outpoint? This is related to Domain Analysis Testing using Binders technique in software testing
can anyone tell me these all points?
is onpoint is 200 or 199 or 201?

What did you do to answer this yourself? How do the findings not satisfy you?

What references/resources have you referred to?  How do they define these terms?
